# Complexity of detecting a semiprime

Tags: computational-complexity, semiprimes

A semiprime is a number that factors into exactly two primes. The decision problem SEMIPRIME decides whether a given number is a semiprime.

It follows from the polynomiality of the AKS test that SEMIPRIME is both in NP and in co-NP: to verify "yes" write the input *n* as a *n=pq* and test that both *p* and *q* are primes, and to verify "no" test whether either *n* is a prime, or write *n* as a product of more than two nontrivial factors.

The prime example until 2002 of a decision problem that belongs to NP∩co-NP and was not known to be in P used to be PRIME, to decide whether a given number is a prime.

I wonder if more is known about the complexity of SEMIPRIME, in particular whether it is known to be in P? I have not been able to google any relevant information.

Comment: if SEMIPRIME was in P, couldn't you also place PRIME in P? for PRIME($n$) just answer SEMIPRIME($2\cdot n$)?

Comment: True, the output to PRIME(*n*) should be the same as to SEMIPRIME(*n²*), is what you mean. But we know PRIME ∊ P already, so this does not help.

Comment: Determining whether a number is a semiprime is basically as difficult as factoring. It is not known in which class factoring is , probably in NP. RSA is based on the difficulty to factor a semiprime.

Comment: Surely factoring "is in NP" in the broad sense that a prime factorization has a polynomial-time verifier consisting of the factorization itself together with a proof that the factorization evaluates to the input number. But why would SEMIPRIME be as difficult as factorization? Is there a reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "factors congruent to themselves"? Could you give some small numerical examples?